# Помогите исправить ошибку Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, рекурсия

Делаю лабораторную работу, задание:

> Задание: 1)    Создать программу рекурсивного поиска корня методом
>   проб. 1)   Написать рекурсивную процедуру/функцию для решения задачи,
>   условие которой приведено ниже. Использовать динамический одномерный
>   массив. Нарисовать полное дерево рекурсивных вызовов для N=8
>   Подсчитать для этого дерева глубину вызовов и объем рекурсии.
>
> Варианты заданий:
>   8.Для заданного одномерного массива X из N элементов проверить, что для всех элементов массива выполняется условие cos Xi > 0. В
>   рекурсивной функции каждый раз делить рассматриваемую часть массива на
>   две части: одну треть и две третьих, проверяя условие с помощью этой
>   же функции сначала в левой части (1/3), а затем при необходимости и в
>   правой части. Рекурсивные вызовы заканчивать, когда останется только
>   один или два элемента в рассматриваемой части массива.

На с# получился такой код:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace programm
{
    class Program
    {
        class Mass
        {
            public double[] A;//Объявление массива 
            public Mass(int N)//Конструктор класса. В параметрах передается количество элементов массива (введенное в main)
            {
                A = new double[N];//Инициализация динамического массива (трудоемкость 1)
                Random rand = new Random();//Объявление и инициализация класса Random (трудоемкость 1)
                for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)//Цикл заполнения массива случайными значениями (трудоемкость всего цикла 1+3n+3n)
                    A[i] = rand.Next(-100, 100); //(трудоемкость 3)
            }

            public int Cos(int first, int last)//Получаем индексы первого и последнего элемента массива (подмассива).
            {
                if (last+1-first < 3)//Проверяем остался ли в подмассиве один или два элемента (трудоемкость 3, условие выполнится N раз)
                {
                    if (Math.Cos(A[first]) < 0)//Проверяем условие задачи (трудоемкость 4)
                        return 1;//Возвращаем 1 (трудоемкость 1)
                    else return 0;//Иначе, возвращаем 0 (трудоемкость 1)
                }
                else//Иначе
                    return Cos(first, (first + last) / 3) + Cos((first + last) / 3, last);//Вызываем функцию для первой трети и остальной части массива и складываем их результаты. (трудоемкость 11)
            }
        }
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            int N;
            Console.WriteLine("Введите N"); //(трудоемкость 1)
            N = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());//Ввод количества элементов (трудоемкость 4)
            Mass M = new Mass(N);//Создание экземпляра класса. (трудоемкость 2)
            Console.WriteLine(M.Cos(0, N - 1));//Вызов метода Cos и вывод результата на экран. (трудоемкость 5)
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}

/*
Итоговая трудоемкость функции main равна: 12.
Используя метод апроксимации, получим 0.
Итоговая трудоемкость конструктора равна:6N+6.
Используя метод апроксимации, получим N.
Итоговая трудоемкость функции Cos: 20N-12.
Используя метод апроксимации, получим N.
Итого N.
*/
```

При запуске и вводе числа 8 получаю ошибку

> Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException

:

```
Введите N
8

Process is terminated due to StackOverflowException.
```

Помогите пожалуйста понять, что я делаю не так?

Comment: Рекурсия, Переполнение стека

Comment: спасибо, я тоже прочитал сообщение об ошибке, вопрос заключается в том, что я не понимаю почему переполнение происходит.. т.к. мне кажется я делаю все правильно

Comment: @danilashrainer: Дополнил ответ, откопал ещё одну ошибку

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ваша проверка на рекурсию неправильная. Например, для случая `first = 0`, `last = 2` у вас индекс «внутреннего» элемента равен `(first + last) / 3 == first`, то есть рекурсивный вызов `Cos((first + last) / 3, last)` будет с теми же аргументами.

Судя по всему, ваш интервал от `first` до `last` — *полуоткрытый*, то есть, ваши элементы начинаются от `first` и заканчиваются на `last - 1`. Если так, то ваша проверка на длину подмассива неверна: нужно вместо `last+1-first < 3` просто `last - first < 3`.

Затем, у вас совершенно неверное вычисление делящего элемента. Если, например, `first = 30`, `last = 33`, ваше вычисление даст значение `21`, которое не ледит между `30` и `33`! Вычисляйте так:

```
else //Иначе
{
    int middle = first + (last - first) / 3;
    return Cos(first, middle) + Cos(middle, last);
}
```

---

Да, и вызывать нужно так:

```
Console.WriteLine(M.Cos(0, N));
```

Comment: а там точно целочисленное деление нужно?

Comment: @Grundy: Ну там всё равно индексы. Что делать с дробным значением? Разве что дальше округлять.